# How do I correctly return to details.html after updating using HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django

After I update my post I want to be redirected back to my details page. But it's not working. Heres my Url

```
 url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
```

and here is my View

```
def post_update(request, id=None):
instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:list', args=id))

context = {
    "title": instance.title,
    "instance": instance,
    "form": form
}
return render(request, "posts/post_form.html", context)
```

here is the error message that I get

```
Reverse for 'list' with arguments '('3',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/$']
```

I have also tried changing this

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:list', args=id))
```

to this

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:list', args=instance.id))
```

and

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:list', args=Post.id))
```

How do I correct this

Answer (score 1):

You were redirecting to `list` url, but you want to redirect to `detail` instead?

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts:detail', args=id))
```

Comment: thanks I've been coding to many hours thanks for catching that